# 38:10: error: member reference base type 'Node *' is not a structure or union *prev->next = temp;

Tags: c++, linked-list

Code is to insert element at the end position of link list. I am passing pointer to the Node pointer to insert method while doing so I am getting the error `member reference base type 'Node *' is not a structure or union` on line number 38, which is `*prev->next = temp;`. Please explain the issue and if you provide the solution on the same logic, it will be better.

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

struct Node {
  int data;
  Node* next;
};

void insertElement(Node**, Node**, int);
void printLinkList(Node** head);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  Node *head = NULL, *prev = NULL;
  int num, pos;
  char controller;
  cout << "To add element to link list press y, to quit press any other key: ";
  cin >> controller;
  while(controller == 'y') {
    cout << "Enter element: ";
    cin >> num;
    insertElement(&head, &prev, num);
    cout << "To add next element to link list press y, to quit press any other key: ";
    cin >> controller;
  }
  printLinkList(&head);
  return 0;
}

void insertElement(Node **head, Node **prev, int num) {
  Node *temp = new Node();
  temp->data = num;
  temp->next = NULL;
  if(*head == NULL) {
    *head = temp;
  }
  if(*prev != NULL) {
    *prev->next = temp;
  }
  *prev = temp;
}

void printLinkList(Node** head) {
  Node* temp = *head;
  while(temp != NULL) {
    cout << temp->data << ", ";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Learn the operator precedence.

Comment: *prev->next is *(prev->next)

Comment: getting same error after changing *prev->next to *(prev->next)

Comment: @Pradosh Yes, those are equivalent. You want `(*prev)->next`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax of pointers to structures - linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987691/syntax-of-pointers-to-structures-linked-lists)

Answer (score 3):

The error message would be self-explanatory if your expression was less complex. Still, it is reasonably straight-forward when taken out of context.

> `member reference base type 'Node *' is not a structure or union`

This says that at some point you tried to access the member of a pointer to `Node`, which is not allowed because only structures and unions have members. (The compiler is using "structure" to cover both `struct` and `class`.) In particular, pointers do not have members.

Hopefully this rings true. If `temp` is a `Node*`, then the expression `temp.data` does not make sense; you need first to de-reference the pointer, as in `(*temp).data` or the equivalent `temp->data`. So what is going on in your code?

At the problematic point in your code, you have a pointer-to-pointer, which is often not the best approach. The pointer-to-pointer, `prev`, appears in the sub-expression `prev->next`, which is equivalent to `(*prev).next`. Consider that last expression. Since `prev` is `Node**`, a single de-reference gives `Node*` which is the situation from above: trying to access the `next` field does not make sense unless you first de-reference the pointer, as in `(**prev).next`. This is close to what you wrote, but not quite.

The correct expression, `(**prev).next` is equivalent to `(*prev)->next`. Your expression, `*prev->next`, is equivalent to `*(prev->next)` or `*((*prev).next)`. There is a difference in the order of evaluation. This difference is one reason pointers-to-pointer are challenging to manage correctly. (The language is not designed to succinctly accommodate pointers-to-pointer-to-structure. Instead, it assumes the more likely scenario for two levels of indirection is pointer-to-structure-with-pointer-member.)

---

Since you are coding in C++ instead of C, there is a nifty language feature that helps avoid this problem. Have `insertElement` accept `Node` pointers by reference instead of by address. This reduces the complexity of your expressions, removing your current problem, and addresses the future problem where you never checked if the function's parameters are null. (You have a check for `*head` being null, but that check blows up if `head` itself is null.)

```
void insertElement(Node *&head, Node *&prev, int num);
```

With this change, occurrences inside the function body of `head*` become `head`, of `prev*` become `prev`, and the call to the function becomes `insertElement(head, prev, num);` (no address-of operator). You get simpler syntax so you can focus on the logic of inserting an element.

See also [Meaning of *& and **& in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789806/meaning-of-and-in-c).

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem: #include <iostream>
#include <list>
struct Shape {
    virtual void Draw() = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {}};
struct Circle : public Shape { virtual void Draw(){std::cout << "I am a Circle\n";}};
void drawShapes(std::list<Shape*>& shapes){
    std::list<Shape*>::iterator pShape = shapes.begin();
    std::list<Shape*>::iterator pEnd = shapes.end();
    for (;pShape!=pEnd;pShape++)
        (*pShape)->Draw();}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    Circle circle;
    std::list<Shape*>geometries={ &circle };
    drawShapes(geometries);
    return 0;}